# JavaScript - Make a function to update variables by passing an object?

Tags: javascript, html, function, object, sql-update

I want to be able to update any number of variables in my document with one function that takes an object as a parameter. What I want:

```
<span id="firstname"></span>
<span id="lastname"></span>

...

function updateStuff(obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        document.getElementById(key).innerHTML = valueAssociatedWithKey;
    }
}

...

updateStuff({
    firstname: "John",
    lastname: "Doe"
})
```

End result would have `<span id="firstname">John</span>` and `<span id="lastname">Doe</span>`

Is there any way to accomplish this?
If not, is there a better alternative?

For those familiar with [RiotJS's self.update function](http://riotjs.com/api/#updating), I'm essentially trying to recreate this in JavaScript without pulling in their entire library for one little function.

Note: I would like to do this without ANY libraries, including JQuery.

Thank you!

Comment: You pretty much wrote everything, all you're missing is that you can get properties by their name with `object[property]` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you're missing is getting the value associated with key, which you can get by doing `obj[key]`.

Example:

```
function updateStuff(obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        document.getElementById(key).innerHTML = obj[key];
    }
}

updateStuff({
    firstname: "John",
    lastname: "Doe"
});
```

**JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/xmhgxqj7/**

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't see that. Thanks a bunch.